# How to remove bullet text in button using bright script?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I added two Button in ROKU. But I use Button tag in Roku But every time Set Bullet-in button text. Is there any way to remove bullet text in Roku.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Button tag takes a default "iconUri". To remove the bullet, set "iconUri" field as empty or an image uri that does not exist.

```
<Button id="button1" text="Button Name" iconUri="" />
```

OR

```
<Button id="button1" text="Button Name" iconUri="PKG://S" />
```

OR (set the "iconUri" field in respective "brs" file)

```
m.button1 = m.top.findnode("button1")
m.button1.iconUri = ""
```

Comment: Here the not question part but also By default Focus bullet text remove using `focusedIconUri=""`. Thank you.